# EEPROM not consistent over reboot

Tags: esp8266, eeprom, memory

I'am using a Wemos D1 mini V3.0.0 (esp 8266 core).

I tried to save a structure in EEPROM memory but all data are lost when i reboot the board.

I am using these basics functions :

```
int cle_verif = 519; //verification key

struct sauvegarde_data {
  int cle; //verification key
  int mode_ecl; //var
  int r; //var
  int v; //var
  int b; //var
};
sauvegarde_data customVar;

void sauvegardeEEPROM() {
  EEPROM.put(0, customVar);
  EEPROM.commit();
}

void chargeEEPROM() {
  // Lit la mémoire EEPROM
  EEPROM.get(0, customVar);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("cle : "+String(customVar.cle));
  Serial.println("mode eclairage : "+String(customVar.mode_ecl));
  Serial.println("r : "+String(customVar.r));
  Serial.println("v : "+String(customVar.v));
  Serial.println("b : "+String(customVar.b));
  if(customVar.cle != cle_verif){ // check if the key is correct
    initialiserEEPROM();
  }
}

void initialiserEEPROM(){
  // Valeurs par défaut
  customVar.cle=cle_verif;
  customVar.mode_ecl=0;
  customVar.r=15;
  customVar.v=15;
  customVar.b=15;
  sauvegardeEEPROM();
}
```

and then, i ran the following code to initialize the EEPROM memory with default values :

```
EEPROM.begin(128);
initialiserEEPROM(); // initialisation
customVar.b=2; // change cached var value
chargeEEPROM(); // read EEPROM memory
```

the output is customVar.b=15 which is correct and it means it has been saved in EEPROM.

Any idea ?

Have a great day.

PS: i use four libraries which are FastLed, EEPROM, ESP8266WiFi, ESP8266WebServer.
My goal is to save the LEDs color for a more pertinent reboot.

Comment: So, what exactly doesn't work? You wrote, 15 has been stored correctly... please also post your setup and loop code (at least those parts that are relevant)

Comment: I don't see EEPROM.begin(). https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries.html#eeprom

Comment: Hello, my loop code is not really relevant as it is only server.handle. I then get an argument over a webpage which updates eeprom with sauvegardeEEPROM(); function but that is all

Comment: EEPROM.begin was in my setup function i'm sorry :-/ I edited the post so you can see it :-)

Comment: The part which is not working in when i reboot the card, all the data i saved are lost.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out i'm just really stupid. I spent something like 7 hours to make things work but i just selected the wrong card during the whole time.

Sorry for bothering you guys :-/